# Always Be Closing

Tags: script, closing

> > > > > > > > > > [image: ABC]

Gist:

https://gist.github.com/WillSullivan/6732086#file-alwaysbeclosing

#### Description:

A userscript that adds easy to reach and use buttons for the most common closure tasks.

As configured, the buttons are added to every question in the questions list or in the close vote review page.

#### Usage:

> > > > > > > > [image: Image of buttons]

- OT  :  Off topic because "it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center"
- OB  :  Opinion based
- TB  :  Too Broad
- UC  :  Unclear
- TL  :  "Too Localized", a simple typo was the problem, of no benefit to others
- LIB :  Asking for links, libraries, books, articles, feminine hygiene products...
- NE  :  No effort
- SU  :  Shoulda been asked on SuperUser
- SF  :  Shoulda been asked on ServerFault

Once clicked, an ugly span will be revealed to let you know if your vote was tallied or not.  Check the console for messages when it fails.

Note that the Off Topic close flag requires a custom reason be submitted, which then ends up a comment on the question.  A default is given in the script, but feel free to update it.

#### Updates:

6/18/2015: Updated two close reasons--UC and TL--to reflect code and close reason changes

4/22/2017: Updated dependencies to substitute Vanillajs for jQuery. Possible fix for the buttons not showing up sometimes added.  Refactored for cleanup, so I won't be as embarrassed of this crap. Fixed issue in Edge (Creator's update?) where the buttons weren't being added at all.  Note, this update may not work with older browsers, and I can't be arsed to test.  Good luck with them.  Still not working in the review queue, which I don't use much, so meh.

5/22/2017: Hey, look, https.

Comment: I can't get the gist of your gist.